# Uniswapv3 IQuoter revert

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm trying to use uniswapv3 IQuoter to get a quote:

```
IQuoter iQuoter = IQuoter(0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6); // quoter address

address sellingAddress = 0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599; // wbtc address
address wethAddress = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
uint24 poolFee = 3000;
uint amountIn = 2962367;
uint160 sqrtPriceLimit = 0;

//get estimated token output
uint tokenOutput = iQuoter.quoteExactInputSingle(wethAddress, sellingAddress, poolFee, amountIn, sqrtPriceLimit);
```

I keep getting a `revert` error

but when I use the same code in truffle, it works:

```
const amountOut = await iQuoter.quoteExactInputSingle(
    "0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599",
    "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
    3000,
    2962367,
    0);

console.log(amountOut.toString());

//console
497004266064646932
```

why does this happen?

Comment: The doc say "These functions are not marked view because they rely on calling non-view functions and reverting to compute the result.", so the "revert" is its designed behaviour.  Ref: https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/v1.1.1/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol#L7-L8